Laying out components on a screen bottom-up in Jetpack Compose
I am trying to build a screen for a simple Calculator app using Compose. My idea was to start at the bottom and then build my way to the top, which means, all the space that is left in the upper part of the screen (after laying out the buttons) should be occupied by a textfield. I've gotten this far:

This is the code I wrote to achieve the above:
@Composable
fun Screen(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    keys: List<AppButtonProperties>
) {
    Box(
        modifier = modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        contentAlignment = Alignment.BottomEnd
    ) {
        Column {
            TextField(
                value = "",
                onValueChange = {},
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .fillMaxHeight(0.35f)
                    .padding(bottom = 5.dp),
                colors = TextFieldDefaults.colors(unfocusedContainerColor = Color.Red) //colored for demonstration purpose
            )
            Box {
                LazyVerticalGrid(
                    columns = GridCells.Fixed(4),
                ) {
                    items(keys) { key ->
                        AppButton(modifier = Modifier.padding(2.dp), key)
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
}

As is evident in the code, I made a very lousy attempt of fillMaxHeight(0.35f) to make the textfield fill up most of the available space, but surely, there's a better of doing it. Please help.

Unless you plan on a lot more buttons in a scrollable area, it is unclear why you are using LazyVerticalGrid(). Instead, you could replace your Box()/LazyVerticalGrid() with five Row() widgets. Then, you could use the weight() modifier on the TextField() instead of the 0.35f magic value.

@CommonsWare I just felt grid implementation is cleaner/more convenient way of laying out items in a grid. What I needed was a non-lazy flavour of vertical grid, but we don't have any, so I went for the lazy one instead. Does it cause any performance issue when you use lazy layouts with too few items? Also, thank you very much for your suggestion on weight() modifier.

"What I needed was a non-lazy flavour of vertical grid, but we don't have any" -- there is https://github.com/touchlane/gridpad-android and probably others.
